# Eloquent query adding a new field depending on a pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make some query with Eloquent but cannot get the result I really want. Using Laravel 6.

I have the next tables:

**Table Users:**

```
id  | user
============
1   | Andy
```

**Table Colors:**

```
id  | color
============
1   | red
2   | blue
3   | white
4   | green
5   | black
```

**Table user_colors:**

```
id  | user_id   | color_id
==========================
1   | 1         | 1
1   | 1         | 4
```

What I want is something to get all the colors, but mark as active the ones in the pivot. Something like this:

```
id  | color | active
====================
1   | red   | 1
2   | blue
3   | white
4   | green | 1
5   | black
```

Any idea?

Comment: you expecting using relationship or join query is fine ?

Comment: Do you have models for these tables? If so, please can you show the relationships you've set up between the models.

Comment: So are you wanting a collection of all colours with a single given users chosen colours marked as active? Or a list of all colours with counts for each user? I assume the first scenario

Comment: @Hamelraj to get a join should to be ok, I just want an array of the list of colors. and marked as active those that matches on the pivot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return a collection of `Color` objects with the one's associated with the given user given a property of `active` set to true

```
$user_colors = User::find(1)->colors;
$colors = Colors::all()->transform(function ($color) use ($user_colors) {
    if ($user_colors->contain($color)) {
        $color->active = true;
    }
    return $color;
});
```

Whilst this should achieve the result you need, without knowing the context in which you want to use it, it may be inefficient.

Comment: This one sounds interesting. The context is to show a list of colors available in the system, and mark as active those that the user has activated and stored on user_colors

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this task. One of them could be to use appends in models.

Appends are attributes that you can dynamically add to your model class.

E.g. you can edit your `Color` model like this:

```
class Color extends Model {

    // Your code...

    protected $appends = ['active'];

    public function getActiveAttribute() {
        $is_active = UserColor::whereColorId($this->id)->first();
        if (!is_null($is_active)) return true; // Or 1, up to you
        return false; // Or 0, up to you
    }
}
```

If you use this method, you can access to `$color->active` attribute.

Note that this is only one of the different methods that you can use to do this task.

Reference: [Laravel Appends Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json)